# How would I express the elements of $(AB^T)_{ij}$ both ways?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $p \times n$ and $q \times n$ matrices with rows $(\mathbf a_1,\ldots,\mathbf a_n)$ and $(\mathbf b_1,\ldots,\mathbf b_n)$ respectively (by default the vector $\mathbf a_i$ is thought of as column when taken by itself, even if it is from a $row$ of $A$).

Show that 
$$
A B^T = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf a_i \mathbf b_i^T
$$
by expressing the elements $(AB^T)_{ij}$ both ways.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write "...with rows $(\mathbf{a_1}, \ldots, \mathbf{a_p})$ and respectively $(\mathbf{b_1}, \ldots, \mathbf{b_q})$"?

Comment: My professor gave us this question and this is how he stated it

Comment: "My professor gave us this question and this is how he stated it" - sounds like homework. What have you done so far?